# SQL Server update foreign key to point to the first in a set of duplicated items

Tags: sql-server

I have a mapping table with a foreign key column which points to a table of strings. In the string table, there are duplicates (which I plan to delete). Before I delete the duplicates, I want to update the mapping table so that each foreign key index points to the first instance of the string being pointed to.

The section of schema I am working with is as follows:

ImageTagMap

- imageTagMapId
- imageId
- tagId

ImageTag

- tadId
- tagName

i.e. there are duplicate records of tagName which I will delete but I need each mapping in ImageTagMap to point to the first tag with the same 'tagName' as the instance being deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common issue and actually pretty simple to tackle (once you know how :).

I created some sample temp data which consists of 4 tags (2 dupes of 2 tags) and 2 images.  Each image has 2 tags but the images points to different versions of the same tag.

In the end, you get 2 images with 2 tags each, and then you can delete the other 2 tags:

**How to Fix It**

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY #ImageTag.tagName ORDER BY #ImageTag.tagName) as TagRank, #ImageTagMap.imageTagMapId, #ImageTagMap.imageId, #ImageTag.tagId, #ImageTag.tagName
into #UpdateTable1
from #ImageTagMap
    join #ImageTag on #ImageTagMap.tagId = #ImageTag.tagId

select #UpdateTable1.tagId AS idToDelete, RowToKeep.tagId AS idToKeep
into #UpdateTable2
from #UpdateTable1
    join (select * from #UpdateTable1 where TagRank = 1) RowToKeep ON #UpdateTable1.tagName = RowToKeep.tagName
where #UpdateTable1.TagRank != 1

-- update the data
update #ImageTagMap
set tagId = #UpdateTable2.idToKeep
from #ImageTagMap
    join #UpdateTable2 ON #ImageTagMap.tagId = #UpdateTable2.idToDelete

-- verify the data
select *
from #ImageTagMap
    join #ImageTag on #ImageTagMap.tagId = #ImageTag.tagId

-- delete the dupes
delete #ImageTag
from #ImageTag
    left outer join #ImageTagMap on #ImageTag.tagId = #ImageTagMap.tagId
where #ImageTagMap.imageTagMapId is null
```

Let me know if that does it for you.

You should also consider throwing a unique constraint on the tagName column if it's not supposed to allow duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this recently in SQL Server.  Basically it is a varient of the SQL below.  I had duplicate attribute IDs.  You want to set the ORDER BY so the results are in an order where the one you want to keep is before the one(s) you want to keep.

```
WITH numbered AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY attribute_id ORDER BY attribute_id) AS _dupe_num,
[attribute_id] FROM [dbo].[asset_attr] WHERE 1=1)

-- Change this to Delete after
SELECT * FROM numbered WHERE _dupe_num > 1;
```

Comment: Hi Sqldba, this is great for identifying and deleting the duplicates, but what I was really wondering was how to tackle the update part.